# What does this 'x' mean on the stem of the voice's note, above the notehead?

Tags: notation, voice

I was looking at the score for Arnold Schoenberg's  *Pierrot lunaire* (On [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQVkbKULKpI)), and on the voice staff none of the notes are connected with each other and they have this *x* or * on their stem:

[image]

What do these symbols mean?

At the beginning of the piece, instead of *soprano*, it says *Rezitation* (Recitation), does this have anything to do with the *x*'s?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just googled **Sprechstimme**

According to Encyclopaedia Britannica it's a cross between speaking and singing in which the tone quality of speech is heightened and lowered in pitch along melodic contours indicated in the musical notation.

Its introduction is especially associated with the composer Arnold Schoenberg, who first used it in his Pierrot Lunaire (1912).

Comment: Indeed. Wikipedia says: "In Schoenberg's musical notation, Sprechstimme is usually indicated by small crosses through the stems of the notes, or with the note head itself being a small cross." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprechgesang#Sprechstimme

Answer (score 6):

One other note:

*Sprechstimme* (a style Schoenberg invented, and indicated with the crossed notes) is derived from the older technique of [*recitativo*](https://youtu.be/TSVgkBq4v30?t=27), a sort of half-singing half-speaking style used for conversations in opera (mostly when the composer didn't want to interrupt the music by switching to actual speaking).

*Sprechstimme* is somewhat freer, and doesn't try to hit exact notes; instead, it's focused on the contours. But Schoenberg still labelled his *sprechstimme* pieces as *Rezitation*: the German form of *recitativo*. That word at the beginning of the piece is another indication that he wants *sprechstimme* there.